# postman SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

[image]
[image]

After using the path finder also i am getting the error in postman for setting the variable  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

Answer (score 1):

you have extra point

value = jsonData[0]

Answer (score 0):

remove .

```
value=jsonData[0].lotCpId
```